# cant send email using exchange server 2013

Tags: exchange

I am trying to setup my own personal exchange server.  I have my own domain and have prepared the necessary a and mx records accordingly. 
I have setup my send connector according to Microsoft specifications and numerous forums on the internet. 
I have made sure that the appropriate ports are open, and mxtoolbox shows nothing wrong when it tests my smtp connection and MX records.
I can telnet to my email server from anywhere.
I can send and receive email internally no problem, and i can receive email externally no problem.  However my problem comes to when trying to send externally.  The email no matter what stays in queue.  Any suggestions, recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Post your send connector config please, as it's the culprit

Comment: under genereal the status is enabled.  Delivery Network settings is set to MX, Smarhost set to none, and Use the external DNS lookup settings on servers with transport roles unchecked. scoping  address space smtp, *, 1.  source server is my server and fqdn my servers fully qualified domain name

Comment: Get a remote server MX's record, and try a telnet there from your server. I want to know if you blocked the port 25 in exit.

Comment: I am able to telnet into my server from anywhere

Comment: Not into yours, into another server. (like try to connect to hotmail, yahoo, or any other remote server). Some router admin block outgooing email..

Comment: i tried to telnet to hotmail.com with port 25 and it did not succeed.  could not open connection to the host

Comment: hotmail's mx server I meant, not directly hotmail.com, or your ISP mail server.. any server that accept mail

Comment: i tried mx1.hotmail.com and by ip address

Comment: try on port 25, forget to told it.. telnet some_isp_server 25

Comment: i did telnet mx1.hotmail.com 25...... could not open connection to host

Comment: same with rogers mx server

Comment: Check your router, it mean it block port 25 in exit. Some admin do that to prevent unauthorized computer/server to send email. Let me know, will write as a answer if you find the problem in the router.

Comment: I have port 25 open.  its my personal network. Ive done port checks and the results show port 25 open

Comment: port 25 open when I talk to you, but port 25 close when you try to talk to me, understand what I mean. Its not the same thing. Usually all router dont block in exit, but it can happen.

Comment: I get it. I just dont see an option to unblock it.  I have port 25 setup for port forwarding and yes I know thats in

Answer (score 0):

Rogers (Canadian ISP) blocks outbound connections on port 25 for residential plans, except to their own SMTP servers. This is the culprit.

I would recommend using another SMTP server as a smarthost like Rogers (just kidding) or SendGrid or MailChimp (just make sure you relay to them on TCP port 587).